# Can I Transpile for ES6-ES5 without npm, VS, Node, etc. and just the JS code itself somehow?

Tags: javascript, firefox, es6-promise, let

I am trying to get Firefox to run a Promise in ES6 but run into the 'let' keyword triggering an error;

SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier

Changing the script tag to include;
type="application/javascript;version=1.7"
did not work, so I am seeking to Transpile the code.

My situation is that there is nothing being used except a text editor. No NPM, not Node or Angular, no Visual Studio, nothing. So when I investigated the Compilers, I saw no option to let me Transpile this code without any of these other tools/editors/etc.

Is there an option where I do not have to learn, use, install, configure, adapt, another tool and just Transpile it outright, or is there some server-specific reason that this cannot be done? What ARE my options?

Thanks in advance! Hoping someone can school me in ES6 and getting it to work with Firefox so it doesn't trigger the errors and use 'let' the way it is intended to be ran.

Comment: Which FF version are you using / testing ? Firefox has basic support for "let" according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Otherwise just try out https://babeljs.io/repl/ if your app code isn't too big / complex. And I've tested the "let" keyword on FF 42.0 it is working.

Comment: The only option for transpiling via Babel or anything else like that is to do it as some server-side build step. So the direct answer to your question is "no".

Comment: I'm using Firefox 43.0.1.

Yes, the code is very complex in itself and there is a lot intermingled outside of the part that I am doing. Old deprecated code is in the main site, and I am confined to working inside of what they currently have, so I am handicapped somewhat, if you will.

I have NO server-level access, not even for log files, and this is a cloud based Amazon web service which is new to me. So just learning and using something I have not tried before isn't an option for me in this situation. (I need time to learn on something not as crucial).

Comment: If Firefox will allow the use of the 'let' keyword, then I will keep working on that route. The thing is, I should at least be getting past the syntax error, especially with that script tag pointing at the specific version to use, right? I mean, even if not blocked/scoped correctly, it should let me past that initial syntax error.

What other things could cause Firefox to not see the 'let' keyword as being allowed? Another script or code? Does stating a version need to be done immediately, instead of on the script using the new identifier 'let'?

Comment: It would be useful if you  show the code you are trying to run, probably is not a browser issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client-side JSX transpiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577282/client-side-jsx-transpiling)

Comment: Do you really need all of ES6 or just Promise?

Answer (score 1):

You can write ES6 in the browser with the babel-standalone

```
<div id="output"></div>
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Your custom script here -->
<script type="text/babel">
  const getMessage = () => "Hello World";
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getMessage();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use ES6 without nodeJs, Follow the below steps

1. Import babel script
2. use `<script type="text/babel"></script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`
3. Write your ES6 code inside

Cons:
You need write all ES6 code in the same HTML page, for example, if index.html is an entry point for the application, then you need to include ES6 code in the index.html page using the script tag of type "text/babel". You can't import the external ES6 file, it will throw cross-origin error.