# Client-side JSX transpiling

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, jsx, transpiler

I want to create React applications with JSX and not have to use a terminal or any server-side/dev environment commands. The environment we are using doesn't allow for commands to be run in the dev environment and these applications will be purely statically hosted on a CDN.

So I know I can simply include Babel's browser.js to do the JSX transpiling in the browser. Perfect. My concern is that Babel apparently stopped supporting this and modern versions of Babel have it removed. Is there another solution? Is [babel-standalone](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone) what I should be using?

I fully understand the performance penalties in using this in production, but our use case (which I can't imagine is that unusual of a use case with so many great and simple online HTML/JS IDEs) allows for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you don't want to bundle your own files, [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone) is what you should use.
See prototyping on the official [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/):
I'm using the CDN from the links above in a "codepen like" demo-project, and it works fine.